# How to get monospace characters with pmboxdraw?

Tags: fonts, typewriter

I want to have a monospace font for block characters, U+2580, U+2584, U+2588 (see below).

For those characters, I use pmboxdraw.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}
\begin{document}\tiny\begin{verbatim}
████ ▄▄▄ █▄   ▄ ▄▄▄▄▀▀ ▄█▄ ▄▄▄ ▄ ▀█▄▀▄█▄▀ ▄█▀▀  ▀▄▀▄▀▄█ █████
████▄▀ ▀ █▄▀█▄▀▄▀  ▄ ▄ ▄█ ▀ ▀█ ██▄ ▄▀▀▀██ ▀▀▄▄▀▀ █▄▄▀▀█▄█████
████▄▀ ▀██▄ ▄▀█ ▄▀▀▀▄▄▄▄███▀ ▄█ ▄█▀ ▀████▀▀▀█▄ ▀█▀▀ ▄▄▄ ▄████
████▄▄▀ ▄▀▄█ ██ ▄▀█▀▀▄█▄▄▀▀▀▀▄██ █▀▀ ██▄ █▄ ▀ ▄▄▀▄ ▄█▄▄▀▄████
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

However, with `latex`, this results in a non monospace font and the characters are shifted.

[image: non monospace]

How to get monospace characters with pmboxdraw?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the size of space to get the same width as a block:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}
\begin{document}


{%
\tiny\ttfamily \setbox0=\hbox{█}\fontdimen2\font=\wd0
\begin{verbatim}
████ ▄▄▄ █▄   ▄ ▄▄▄▄▀▀ ▄█▄ ▄▄▄ ▄ ▀█▄▀▄█▄▀ ▄█▀▀  ▀▄▀▄▀▄█ █████
████▄▀ ▀ █▄▀█▄▀▄▀  ▄ ▄ ▄█ ▀ ▀█ ██▄ ▄▀▀▀██ ▀▀▄▄▀▀ █▄▄▀▀█▄█████
████▄▀ ▀██▄ ▄▀█ ▄▀▀▀▄▄▄▄███▀ ▄█ ▄█▀ ▀████▀▀▀█▄ ▀█▀▀ ▄▄▄ ▄████
████▄▄▀ ▄▀▄█ ██ ▄▀█▀▀▄█▄▄▀▀▀▀▄██ █▀▀ ██▄ █▄ ▀ ▄▄▀▄ ▄█▄▄▀▄████
\end{verbatim}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes the \makeatletter remained from something else, thanks.

Comment: Nice simplification, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The characters from `pmboxdraw` are monospaced by default (so verbatim is not strictly necessary, although it is convenient to avoid problems with indentation, line endings etc).

However, the empty characters that you draw (for example the 5th character on the first line) are regular space characters, which are not drawn by `pmboxdraw`. This means that the default typesetting of a space character is used, which is not necessarily the same width as the `pmboxdraw` characters, even in monospace.

To avoid this problem a workaround is to draw gray (i.e., shaded) boxes instead of spaces, and redefine a shaded box to be rendered in white. Of course this means that you cannot use shaded boxes anymore, but it is a quick workaround.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}
\usepackage{color}
\makeatletter
\def\pmbd@Shade#1#2{%
  \pmbd@BeginBox{Shade}%
    \ltx@ifundefined{textcolor}{%
      \pmbd@colorwarning{#1}%
    }{%
      \textcolor{white}{\pmbd@Rule\pmbd@W\pmbd@H\z@}
    }%
  \pmbd@EndBox
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}\tiny
\begin{verbatim}
████░▄▄▄░█▄░░░▄░▄▄▄▄▀▀░▄█▄░▄▄▄░▄░▀█▄▀▄█▄▀░▄█▀▀░░▀▄▀▄▀▄█░█████
████▄▀░▀░█▄▀█▄▀▄▀░░▄░▄░▄█░▀░▀█░██▄░▄▀▀▀██░▀▀▄▄▀▀░█▄▄▀▀█▄█████
████▄▀░▀██▄░▄▀█░▄▀▀▀▄▄▄▄███▀░▄█░▄█▀░▀████▀▀▀█▄░▀█▀▀░▄▄▄░▄████
████▄▄▀░▄▀▄█░██░▄▀█▀▀▄█▄▄▀▀▀▀▄██░█▀▀░██▄░█▄░▀░▄▄▀▄░▄█▄▄▀▄████
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Another approach is to use a font that supports these characters and compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. In this case the `pmboxdraw` package is not needed.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
████ ▄▄▄ █▄   ▄ ▄▄▄▄▀▀ ▄█▄ ▄▄▄ ▄ ▀█▄▀▄█▄▀ ▄█▀▀  ▀▄▀▄▀▄█ █████
████▄▀ ▀ █▄▀█▄▀▄▀  ▄ ▄ ▄█ ▀ ▀█ ██▄ ▄▀▀▀██ ▀▀▄▄▀▀ █▄▄▀▀█▄█████
████▄▀ ▀██▄ ▄▀█ ▄▀▀▀▄▄▄▄███▀ ▄█ ▄█▀ ▀████▀▀▀█▄ ▀█▀▀ ▄▄▄ ▄████
████▄▄▀ ▄▀▄█ ██ ▄▀█▀▀▄█▄▄▀▀▀▀▄██ █▀▀ ██▄ █▄ ▀ ▄▄▀▄ ▄█▄▄▀▄████
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comprehensive answer!